# How to print the nth line starting on line n using variables and a for loop in bash using awk

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables, awk

I want to print every 88th line of a file (merged.txt) into a new file, but I want the code to do this starting on every number 1 to 88 and make 88 files

current script:

```
for Y in {1..88}
do
awk  'NR % 88 == $Y'  merged.txt  > atom_$Y.txt
done
```

when I run this I get the error code:

```
illegal field $(), name "Y"
 input record number 1, file merged.txt
 source line number 1
```

Comment: See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) but I'd suggest to do everything within awk itself, no need bash loop

Comment: Here's an example that you can adapt: `seq 10 | awk 'NR % 2{f = "atom_" ++c ".txt"; print > f; close(f)}'` or perhaps you wanted something like `seq 10 | awk '{f = "atom_" (NR%3) ".txt"; print >> f; close(f)}'`

Comment: `awk -v n=88 '{ y=NR%n; print >"atom_"(y?y:n)".txt" }' merged.txt`

Comment: If you are calling `awk` inside a loop, your are probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
awk '{print > "atom_" (NR % 88)}' merged.txt
```

This will create the *atom_0*, *atom_1*, ... files. For more information about redirection in awk, look it up [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

## Update

I studied your solution and found the reason it does not work is because of this expression: `'NR % 88 == $Y'`: The `$Y` variable is not expanded. That means you should place it outside of the single quote like this: `'NR % 88 =='%Y`

## Update 2

I found Claire's solution does not create an *atom_0*, but *atom_88* file. However, *atom_88* is empty. It should work if she adjust the loop to `for Y in {0..87}`

Comment: This appears to solve a different problem than the one in the question.

Comment: thank you so much this worked!!!